# Why can't I set the value of a ProgressBar?

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

friends,thank you for your time!
There's a problem in the codes below in WPF.I use a ProgressBar and a Animation which show the progress of value changes.When the Animation finished,I try to reset the value to 0 ,so that the ProgressBar can begin a new Animation from 0 to 100 again.But the result is that I can't set the value to 0,it seems that it would be 100 forever no matter how I tried!!!!! 
Could you please give me some ideas,thank you!

```
        pbStatus.Value = 0;//Promblem!! pbStatus is a ProgressBar
        Duration dr = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation(100, dr);
        pbStatus.IsIndeterminate = false;
        pbStatus.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        pbStatus.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, da);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx).

---

Summary: There are three ways to set a value after an animation.

1. Set the animation's FillBehavior property to Stop
2. Remove the entire Storyboard. (Not applicable since you have no storyboard)
3. Remove the animation from the individual property.

(1) Set the fill behaviour of the animation to stop:

```
da.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
```

(3) Remove the animation by calling this before setting the new value:

```
pbStatus.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, null);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!It's really helpful!The way to solve this problem may be to stop the animation or remove it.

Comment: Yes, while you answered i added the explicit actions needed.

Comment: Animating progress bars like that is not a very good idea by the way, because it does not say anything about the actual progress; you should use an indeterminate progress bar instead by setting `IsIndeterminate` to true. Also, if this was the answer you were looking for you could accept it by clicking the checkmark outline on the left.

Answer (score 1):

From [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFPB08142008145502PM/WPFPB.aspx):

```
private void CreateDynamicProgressBarControl()
{
    ProgressBar PBar2 = new ProgressBar();
    PBar2.IsIndeterminate = false;
    PBar2.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    PBar2.Width = 100;
    PBar2.Height = 10;
    Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(100.0, duration);
    PBar2.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimation);
    SBar.Items.Add(PBar2);

}
```